# R import vector of int encoded words from text file

Tags: r

I have a Text file with vector of words whose characters are represented with integers. The text file looks like this:

```
x<-c(intToUtf8(c(105,110,100,105,118,105,100,117,117,109)), intToUtf8(c(101,105,110,122,101,108,112,101,114,115,111,110)),...)
```

To use them in R i copy the contents of the text file and paste it in R and when i want to see the value of 'x' it gives me:

```
[1] word1   word2
```

Now my text files contains 9000 words and when i do copy paste it takes very long time to load all the words into R and there are always errors when crossing into new line.

So i tried:

```
x <- readLines("text.txt")
y <- c(x)
y
[1] "intToUtf8(c(105,110,100,105,118,105,100,117,117,109)),intToUtf8(c(101,105,110,122,101,108,112,101,114,115,111,110))"
```

As you can see the result is not what i need.

I also tried loading it with read.table() which gives me a table with only one element at position [1, "V1"] and then using that element but it also didnt work.

How can i load the vector with words into R? I wan't the same result as when i just Copy-Paste it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
y <- "intToUtf8(c(105,110,100,105,118,105,100,117,117,109)),intToUtf8(c(101,105,110,122,101,108,112,101,114,115,111,110))"
x <- strsplit(y, "(?<=\\)\\)),", perl=TRUE)[[1]]
unname(sapply(x, function(str) eval(parse(text=str))))
# [1] "individuum"   "einzelperson"
```

Comment: this is very close, i need to give x the value of just the words ex: "individuum" "einzelperson"... How can i do that @lukeA ?

Comment: You could wrap it in `unname` to get an unnamed vector - see my edit